# Compositum of an infinite family of fields

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $\Gamma$ be an indexing set (possibly infinite). Let $\lbrace E_i\rbrace_{i\in\Gamma}$ be a collection of subfields of $\overline{F}$. Let $E\subseteq \overline{F}$ be the compositum of the $E_i's$. Is it true that for any $\alpha\in E$, there exist $i_1,\dots,i_n\in\Gamma$ such that $\alpha\in E_{i_1}E_{i_2}\dots E_{i_n}$ ?

In other words, is it true that any $\alpha\in E$ lies inside a finite compositum of the$E_i's$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true because $$E= \bigcup_{n\ge 1} \bigcup_{i_1, \dots , i_n \in \Gamma} E_{i_1}\cdots E_{i_n} $$
To prove this equality,check that:

1. RHS is indeed a field containing $\bigcup_{i \in \Gamma} E_i$: hence $E \subseteq$ RHS.
2. RHS $\subseteq E$: well, this is obvious.